# React Native Search and SectionList Causing Flickering and Rendering Issues

Tags: react-native

I am using a SectionList (horizontal) to display filterable data. I'm not sure what is causing this issue, but quite often, after searching, I see gaps in the rendered data or weird flickering behavior. Here are screenshots:

[image: gap in data]

Here is how the data is being displayed:

```
<SectionList
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
          sections={dataSource}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          windowSize={5}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={30}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyListItem />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return index.toString();
          }}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
            <>
              <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>
              {section.data ? (
                <OptimizedFlatList
                  horizontal
                  data={section.data}
                  keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem item={item} navigation={navigation} />
                  )}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
              ) : <ShimmerPlaceHolder
              visible={false}
              LinearGradient={LinearGradient}
              style={[styles.itemPhoto]}
            />}
            </>
          )}
          renderItem={({ item, section, navigation }) => {
            if (section.data) {
              return null;
            }
            return <ListItem item={item} navigation={navigation} />;
          }}
        />
```

and here is how its getting filtered:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // setSearchKey(key)
    // setdataSource(filterData(dataBackup, key))
   
    let mounted = true;
    GetWorkoutsFromAPI().then(items => {
      if (mounted) {
        setdataSource(items);
        setdataBackup(items);

        if(key !== 'null') {
          setSearchKey(key)
        }
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, [key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchKey.length != 0) {
      setdataSource(filterData(dataBackup, searchKey));
    } else {
      setdataSource(dataBackup);
    }
  }, [searchKey]);

  const filterData = (data = [], query) => {
    const foundItems = searchForItem(data, query);
    const foundData = searchForDataInItem(data, query);

    if (foundItems.length !== 0) {
      return foundItems;
    }

    return foundData;
  };
  const searchForItem = (data = [], query) => {
    const result = data
      .filter(i => i.title != null)
      .filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));

    return result;
  };

  const searchForDataInItem = (data = [], query) => {
    return data
      .map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          data: item.data.filter(element =>
            element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()),
          ),
        };
      })
      .filter(item => item.data.length != 0);
  };
```

For the sake of usability, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

as per React Native Guide, you have identified views should be unique for that you have `key` to component

```
<SectionList
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
          sections={dataSource}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          windowSize={5}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={30}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyListItem />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return index.toString();
          }}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
            <View key={`id_${Math.random()}`}> // key for unique component
              <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>
              {section.data ? (
                <OptimizedFlatList
                  horizontal
                  data={section.data}
                  keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem item={item} navigation={navigation} />
                  )}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
              ) : <ShimmerPlaceHolder
              visible={false}
              LinearGradient={LinearGradient}
              style={[styles.itemPhoto]}
            />}
            </View>
          )}
          renderItem={({ item, section, navigation }) => {
            if (section.data) {
              return null;
            }
            return <ListItem item={item} navigation={navigation} />;
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Implemented, thanks. are there any other practices i can do to increase efficiency and UX?

Comment: ok, great @branman3542, before any screen design make part of the screen using ```flex and background``` property of style which gives you the power and confidence